# Scrapy RSS Scraper

Tags: xml, xpath, scrapy, rss

I am trying to scrape an RSS feed from Yahoo ( their Open Company RSS Feed | https://developer.yahoo.com/finance/company.html )

I am trying to scrape the following URL: https://feeds.finance.yahoo.com/rss/2.0/headline?s=BPMX

For some reason my spider isn't functioning, and I think it might have to do with either the XPath that's generated, if not, defining parse_item might have some issues.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider
from YahooScrape.items import YahooScrapeItem

class Spider(CrawlSpider):
    name= "YahooScrape"
    allowed_domains = ["yahoo.com"]
    start_urls = ('https://feeds.finance.yahoo.com/rss/2.0/headline?s=BPMX',)

   def parse_item(self, response):
        self.logger.info('Hi, this is an item page! %s', response.url)
        item = EmperyscraperItem()
        item['title'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="collapsible"]/div[1]/div[2]/span',).extract()                #define XPath for title
        item['link'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="collapsible"]/div[1]/div[2]/span',).extract()                 #define XPath for link
        item['description'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="collapsible"]/div[1]/div[2]/span',).extract()          #define XPath for description
        return item
```

What could be the issue with the code? If not, what are the proper XPath directions to extract the title, desc, and link. I'm new to Scrapy and just need some help figuring it out!

**Edit:** I've updated my spider and converted it into an XMLFeedSpider as shown below:

```
import scrapy

from scrapy.spiders import XMLFeedSpider
from YahooScrape.items import YahooScrapeItem

class Spider(XMLFeedSpider):
    name = "YahooScrape"
    allowed_domains = ["yahoo.com"]
    start_urls = ('https://feeds.finance.yahoo.com/rss/2.0/headline?s=BPMX')    #Crawl BPMX
    itertag = 'item'

    def parse_node(self, response, node):
        self.logger.info('Hi, this is a <%s> node!: %s', self.itertag, ''.join(node.extract()))

        item = YahooScrapeItem()
        item['title'] = node.xpath('item/title/text()',).extract()                #define XPath for title
        item['link'] = node.xpath('item/link/text()').extract()
        item['pubDate'] = node.xpath('item/link/pubDate/text()').extract()
        item['description'] = node.xpath('item/category/text()').extract()                #define XPath for description
        return item

#Yahoo RSS feeds http://finance.yahoo.com/rss/headline?s=BPMX,APPL
```

Now I'm getting the following error:

```
2017-06-13 11:25:57 [scrapy.core.engine] ERROR: Error while obtaining start requests
```

Any idea why the error has occurred? My HTML path looks correct.

Comment: Out of curiosity what's the purpose of scraping an rss feed?  If it's a feed you can just grab the data.

Answer (score 3):

From what I can see, [`CrawlSpider` only works for HTML responses](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/b2d66dc1f0dab48219e8676f5bc43dab207a93a0/scrapy/spiders/crawl.py#L57). So I suggest that you build upon a simpler `scrapy.Spider`, or the more specialized [`XMLFeedSpider`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#xmlfeedspider).

Then, the XPaths you are using in `parse_items` seem to have been built from what your browser rendered as HTML from the XML/RSS feed.
There's no `*[@id="collapsible"]` or `<div>`s in the feed.

Look at `view-source:https://feeds.finance.yahoo.com/rss/2.0/headline?s=BPMX` instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<rss version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <copyright>Copyright (c) 2017 Yahoo! Inc. All rights reserved.</copyright>
        <description>Latest Financial News for BPMX</description>
        <image>
            <height>45</height>
            <link>http://finance.yahoo.com/q/h?s=BPMX</link>
            <title>Yahoo! Finance: BPMX News</title>
            <url>http://l.yimg.com/a/i/brand/purplelogo/uh/us/fin.gif</url>
            <width>144</width>
        </image>
        <item>
            <description>MENLO PARK, Calif., June 7, 2017 /PRNewswire/ -- BioPharmX Corporation (NYSE MKT: BPMX), a specialty pharmaceutical company focusing on dermatology, today announced that it will release its financial results ...</description>
            <guid isPermaLink="false">f56d5bf8-f278-37fd-9aa5-fe04b2e1fa53</guid>
            <link>https://finance.yahoo.com/news/biopharmx-report-first-quarter-financial-101500259.html?.tsrc=rss</link>
            <pubDate>Wed, 07 Jun 2017 10:15:00 +0000</pubDate>
            <title>BioPharmX to Report First Quarter Financial Results</title>
        </item>
```

---

Working spider example:

```
import scrapy

from scrapy.spiders import XMLFeedSpider
#from YahooScrape.items import YahooScrapeItem

class Spider(XMLFeedSpider):
    name = "YahooScrape"
    allowed_domains = ["yahoo.com"]
    start_urls = ('https://feeds.finance.yahoo.com/rss/2.0/headline?s=BPMX',)    #Crawl BPMX
    itertag = 'item'

    def parse_node(self, response, node):
        self.logger.info('Hi, this is a <%s> node!: %s', self.itertag, ''.join(node.extract()))

        item = {}
        item['title'] = node.xpath('title/text()',).extract_first()                #define XPath for title
        item['link'] = node.xpath('link/text()').extract_first()
        item['pubDate'] = node.xpath('link/pubDate/text()').extract_first()
        item['description'] = node.xpath('description/text()').extract_first()                #define XPath for description
        return item
```

Comment: I changed to XMLFeedSpider, and I think I have the right syntax for the path. For some reason I can't get it to properly define start_requests. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: what happens if you remove the `item/` prefix in your XPaths?

Comment: Same issue unfortunately. Any ideas?

Comment: See my proposed spider: I had to fix your start_urls to be a tuple, and removed the `item/` (including the "/") in your XPaths.

Comment: Works very well now! Thank you. I wonder why we needed the tuple bracket.

Comment: `start_urls` needs to point to an iterable of URLs, for example a list or a tuple. `('123')` is the same as `'123'`. `('123',)` on the other hands makes a tuple. You could write `start_urls = 'https://feeds.finance.yahoo.com/rss/2.0/headline?s=BPMX',`